# Interactive Lights Off game

Tags: code-golf

### Intro

I guess most people are familiar with the game [Lights Off](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_Out_%28game%29), but in case someone isn't, here is a short description:

> You start with an NxN grid where each cell in the grid is a light. For this example N=5. There are 2 ways the game can start: either all of the lights are on, or some lights are off. The goal is to turn off all of the lights. If you toggle a light, the lights left, right, above and below it will toggle with it.

#### All Lights on

```
O O O O O  
O O O O O  
O O O O O  
O O O O O  
O O O O O
```

#### Toggled cells

```
Toggled(0,0) | Toggled(1,2)| Toggled(2,4)
X X O O O    |  O O X O O  |  O O O O O
X O O O O    |  O X X X O  |  O O O O X
O O O O O    |  O O X O O  |  O O O X X
O O O O O    |  O O O O O  |  O O O O X
O O O O O    |  O O O O O  |  O O O O O
```

### Task

Make an interactive game of Lights Off with as little code as possible.

**Requirements**

There is a setup phase and a play phase.

The setup phase takes user input to determine the grid size (minimum size of 5) and whether the grid starts with all of the lights on. If the grid should not start with all of the lights on, lights must be selected randomly to start off: at least 1 and at most 20% of the lights.

In the play phase, the grid is displayed to the user and moves are taken as input. The application could use a windowed GUI with lights toggled by clicking, or a text UI which takes typed input of the coordinates of the cell to toggle.

When the user reaches a solved state (all lights off), the application must notify them that they have solved the puzzle, and show how many moves it took.

The use of external resources is not allowed.

If there is anything unclear or missing please let me know :)

#### Related questions

- [Lights Out - Find the solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3429/lights-out-find-the-solution) asks for a computer-generated solution given the input
- [Lights Off!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1899/code-golf-lights-off) is more similar to this one, but non-interactive

Comment: Can you justify why this isn't a duplicate of [question 1](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3429/194)? Do the answers there demonstrably not find the shortest solution?

Comment: Question 1 requires the input of a full grid where the program will find the solution for you, where in this question the program will create a grid for the user to solve.

Comment: do we need to generate a solvable puzzle? Does every puzzle need to be possible to generate? If the size is 2x2, do we really need to start in the solved state?

Comment: If the interesting bit is unchanged and the new bit is as trivial as that, I don't think it adds value to the site.

Comment: @JanDvorak the minimum size is 5x5

Comment: @PeterTaylor which is the interesting bit? Finding the solution is not required here.

Comment: @JanDvorak, "User will be notified if the puzzle is solved and shown how much moves it took."

Comment: @PeterTaylor we're tracking the user's moves here, not the shortest solution. Also, verifying a position is solved is not the same as finding a solution.

Comment: @PeterTaylor The interesting part (in my opinion) is creating a playable game, generating the grid, adjusting the grid according to the players moves and checking the puzzle for completion with as little code as possible. I will edit the question to make it more clear that the player will be in control.

Comment: @JanDvorak If it were we'd have P=NP :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### APL (101)

```
00{⎕←'XO'[1+⍵]⋄1∨.=,⍵:(⍺+1)∇⍵≠(⍳⍴⍵)∊⎕∘+¨Z,⌽¨Z←0∘.,¯1 0 1⋄'SOLVED',⍺}⎕{⍺:⍵ ⍵⍴1⋄~(⍵ ⍵⍴⍳V)∊V?⍨⌊.2×V←⍵*2}⎕
```

The first input is the size, the second input is the start value (0=some off, 1=on). Coordinates are 1-based.

```
      0{⎕←'XO'[1+⍵]⋄1∨.=,⍵:(⍺+1)∇⍵≠(⍳⍴⍵)∊⎕∘+¨Z,⌽¨Z←0∘.,¯1 0 1⋄'SOLVED',⍺}⎕{⍺:⍵ ⍵⍴1⋄~(⍵ ⍵⍴⍳V)∊V?⍨⌊.2×V←⍵*2}⎕
⎕:
      5
⎕:
      1
OOOOO
OOOOO
OOOOO
OOOOO
OOOOO
⎕:
      2 2
OXOOO
XXXOO
OXOOO
OOOOO
OOOOO
⎕:
```

Answer (score 3):

### C++, 564 bytes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;int main(){int n,p,s=0,y,i=0,b;cin>>n>>b;if(n<5)n=5;vector<int>m(n*n,1);srand(time(0));if(b)for(int&c:m)c=rand()<RAND_MAX/6;for(;i<n*n;i++)cout<<m[i]<<(-~i%n?"":"\n");while(find(m.begin(),m.end(),1)!=m.end()){cin>>p>>y;p+=y*n;if(p<0||p>=n*n)continue;m[p]=!m[p];if(p%n)m[p-1]=!m[p-1];if(p%n+1<n)m[p+1]=!m[p+1];if(p>=n)m[p-n]=!m[p-n];if(p+n<n*n)m[p+n]=!m[p+n];for(i=0;i<n*n;i++)cout<<m[i]<<(-~i%n?"":"\n");s++;}cout<<"Solved in "<<s<<" steps."<<endl;}
```

In setup phase, the user should input the grid size first. Then if the grid should starts with all of the lights on, the user should input `0`; otherwise `1`.

In play phase, the user should input the 0-based coordinates of the cell to toggle until all lights off.

Original code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n, p, s = 0, y, i = 0, b;
    cin >> n >> b;
    if(n < 5) n = 5;
    vector<int> m(n * n, 1);
    srand(time(0));
    if (b) for (int& c : m) c = rand() < RAND_MAX / 6;
    for (; i < n * n; i++) cout << m[i] << (-~i % n ? "" : "\n");
    while (find(m.begin(), m.end(), 1) != m.end()) {
        cin >> p >> y;
        p += y * n;
        if (p < 0 || p >= n * n) continue;
        m[p] = !m[p];
        if (p % n) m[p - 1] = !m[p - 1];
        if (p % n + 1 < n) m[p + 1] = !m[p + 1];
        if (p >= n) m[p - n] = !m[p - n];
        if (p + n < n * n) m[p + n] = !m[p + n];
        for (i = 0; i < n * n; i++) cout << m[i] << (-~i % n ? "" : "\n");
        s++;
    }
    cout << "Solved in " << s << " steps." << endl;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer.  You can save a few characters by dropping the `#include <ctime>` and initializing your random number generator with the address of one of your locals; ex `srand(&n);`.  That should be random enough to produce good results.

Comment: @Josh `&n` is fixed on my machine. `srand((int)&m[0]);` is better but I think it is implementation-defined.

Comment: What if you declared your variables at global scope?  Would that add any randomness in to their addresses?

Comment: @Josh Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 3):

## C - 365 characters

```
#define a for(y=0;y<w*w;y++)
*k,i,w,x,y,c=0;main(){scanf("%i %i",&w,&i);k=malloc(4*w*w+8*w)+4*w;i&=1;srand(k);a k[y]=i||ra
nd()<6553;i^=1;for(;;){x=0;a{putchar(k[y]?79:88);x|=k[y]!=i;!((y+1)%w)&&putchar(10);}if(!x&&c
)return printf("won in %i",c);putchar(62);scanf("%i %i",&x,&y);k[x*w-w+y]^=x>0;k[x*w+y-1]^=y>
0;k[x*w+w+y]^=x<w-1;k[x*w+y+1]^=y<w-1;k[x*w+y]^=1;c++;}}
```

In setup phase, it asks the user for two integers: table size and starting state (`0` for off and `1` for on), respectively.

After that, before every move, it will print the grid, then prompt (`>`) the user for 0-based xy coordinates of the point.

Comment: This is beautiful.  You blew the C answer I was working on out of the water.  I did notice that your solution seems to segafault on input `0 0` due to the code `k[x*w+y-1]`.

Comment: Additionally, as per the spec, if the user specifies 'lights off', there is supposed to be at least one light randomly turned on.

Comment: The random part should work. Not sure about your segfault, @Josh, so I added two lines in the grid memory. What OS and compiler are you using? It isn't segfaulting on W7x64.

Comment: an input of `n,` (a number followed by a comma) causes it to go into infinite loop.

Comment: @B1KMusic Coordinates are separated by whitespace, not a comma.

Comment: @Oberon I know. I just thought it was an interesting thing to point out.